# Rice flour: weight to volume

Tags: rice, flour, measurements, conversion

I have a recipe that calls for 1 lb of glutinous rice flour (mochiko), but I don't have a kitchen scale. Approximately how many cups would this be equivalent to?

Answer (score 3):

Around 2.5 - 3 cups (2.8 exactly) but I doubt exactness is necessary for your recipe if your willing to guess by volume.

May I suggest investing in some scales they will only set you back [£14](http://www.procook.co.uk/product/procook-glass-digital-scales-white?utm_source=GoogleShopping&utm_medium=Shopping&utm_campaign=MerchantFeed&gclid=Cj0KEQiA6ounBRCq0LKBjKGgysEBEiQAZmpvA8r_BXkqk2PruB62hAh61EktIQMSKcRtTfJl3tf86LwaAkxD8P8HAQ) for some bog' standard ones which will work just fine for home use.

Comment: [This one](http://www.amazon.com/Ozeri-Digital-Kitchen-Capacity-Stylish/dp/B003E7AZQA/ref=sr_1_2?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1424225842&sr=1-2&keywords=kitchen+scale) is so accurate that it is spooky.

Comment: Thats only $14.40 as well, so whats that in GBP? £9.38, Same price as a nice bottle of wine. Bargain.

Answer (score 1):

According to the blog [Fox in the Kitchen](http://www.foxinthekitchenblog.com/gluten-free-flours/gluten-free-flours-m-to-z/rice-flours/), 1 cup of glutinous rice flour weighs 204 grams, or .45 lbs. So 1 pound would be 2.22 cups.

FYI, 204 grams/cup meshes exactly with what Bob's Red Mill says on its nutrition label for glutinous rice flour. So perfectly, as a matter of fact, that I wonder if that's where the blog listed above got it.

[image: 1]